# Detect MouseUp while something is following the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have been working on a online file system and I want to have users be able to drag and drop files to a new location.  I don't really like how the default drag and drop visuals look so I am not using the conventional methond.  This is what I have so far.

This code is in a .php file which is loaded onto the main page with jQuery

```
    <td draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragFolder(event, \''.$folderId.'\', \''.$folderName.'\')">
      <div class = "single-folder" onMouseUp = "folderDropUp(event, \''.$folderId.'\');">
        <div class = "single-folder-name" id = "single-folder-name-'.$folderId.'">
          <span id = "single-folder-rename-'.$folderId.'" class = "rename-folder-hover">
            '.$folderName.'
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Here is the dragFolder function that I have being fired from "ondragstart".

```
function dragFolder(e, folderId, folderName) {
    var posX, posY, clicked, isDown = false;
    var newFolder;
    document.getElementById("folder_drag_image").setAttribute("folderId", folderId);
    $(".single-folder").mousedown(function() {
        clicked = true;
        isDown = true;
        followCursor(event);
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        clicked = false;
      $('#folder_drag_image').hide();
    if(isDown){
        //dropOnFolder(event, document.getElementById("folder_drag_image").getAttribute("folderId"), )
        isDown = false;
    }
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(clicked == true) {
        $('#folder_drag_image').show();
        $('#folder_drag_image').stop(true, true);
        followCursor(event);
    }
    });
    function followCursor(e) {
      clicked = true;
        posX = e.pageX;
        posY = e.pageY;
        $('#folder_drag_image').animate({left: posX, top: posY});
    }
}
function folderDropUp(e, newFolderId) {
    alert(newFolderId);
    isDown = true;
}
```

Basically what it does is it does is when the mouse goes down over a folder div it shows a fake dragging folder with the id of "folder_drag_image" which follows the mouse until the mouse goes up.

The problem comes here when I want to release the folder ontop of the new folder it will be put in.  Here is the function for that.

```
function folderDropUp(e, newFolderId) {
    alert(newFolderId);
    isDown = true;
}
```

I took out the ajax because that is not part of the problem.  If you look back up the the first code snippet there is a "onMouseUp" listener which triggers a "folderDropUp" event.

The problem is that if I drag my mouse onto folder with the fake drag image the folderDropUp function does not fire.  If I just drag my mouse from anywhere else and it does not have the fake drag image when the function will fire off.

I did try jQuery mouseup function but just got the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how helpful this will be, but by using jQueryUI you could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="single-folder">
                        <div class="single-folder-name" id="single-folder-name-nhaca">
                            <div id="single-folder-rename-nhaca" class="rename-folder-hover">
                                <div>Folder 1</div><div class="folder-drag-image" id="nhaca-drag-image">Folder 1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="single-folder">
                        <div class="single-folder-name" id="single-folder-name-other">
                            <span id="single-folder-rename-other" class="rename-folder-hover">
                                <div>Folder 2</div><div class="folder-drag-image" id="other-drag-image">Folder 2</div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.single-folder{
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
}

.folder-drag-image{
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}

.droppable-ready-to-receive{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //displaying draggable element based on hovered element
    $(".single-folder").on("mouseenter", function(e){
         var drag_image = $(this).find(".folder-drag-image");
         drag_image.css({"display": "block", "top": $(this).offset().top + 20, "left": $(this).offset().left});    
    });

    //resetting draggable element when moving outside the "single-folder" div
    $(".single-folder").on("mouseleave", function(e){
         var drag_image = $(this).find(".folder-drag-image");
         drag_image.css("display", "none");
    });


    //resetting draggable element when not being dragged any longer
    $(".folder-drag-image").draggable({
      stop: function(e) {
          var parent = $(this).parents(".single-folder");
          $(this).css({"display": "none", "top": parent.offset().top, "left": parent.offset().left});     
      }
    });

    //defining what elements can be dropped and what to do when dropped
    $(".single-folder").droppable({
        accept: '.folder-drag-image',
        hoverClass: "droppable-ready-to-receive",
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            console.log("Dropped folder " + ui.draggable.text() + " into " + $(this).find(".folder-drag-image").text());

            //handle folder drop however you need from here
        }
    });
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/skdfLk5b/3/

I'm guessing this is far from a good solution to this, but hopefully it helps somehow.